# Importing a C function

Tags: c

What's wrong with the following import statement? I feel like I'm screwing up something pretty basic here:

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "1_square.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a=4;
    int a_squared=square(a);
    printf("Square of %d is %d\n", a, a_squared);
    return 0;
}
```

```
// 1_square.h
int square(int num);
```

```
// 1_square.c
int square(int num) {
    return num*num;
}
```

```
$ gcc 0_main.c -o 0_main && ./0_main
```

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6qVzAM.o: in function `main': 0_main.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to` square'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Or does `gcc` need a reference to `1_square` in order to build it?

Comment: Note that `1_square.c` should also include the header `1_square.h` — that way you get cross-checking that the function definition matches what other files are told is the type of the `square()` function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok -- for something as basic as this should I just get rid of the `1_square.c` file and use `1_square.h` for everything?

Comment: I assume this is a learning exercise.  Most of your programs will probably need more than one source file.  You will therefore need to be aware of how to use headers to provide cross-checking between source files, and how to write the code in separate files so it works together.  Yes, for this simple example, you could do without the `1_square.h` header and the `1_square.c` source file and simply include the function in the same source file as the `main()` function.  But that's not really realistic, and the purpose of the exercise is to get you to realize how to handle multiple source files.

Comment: See also [Should I use `#include` in headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1804486/15168), [How to structure `#include`s in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/276386/15168), [How to link multiple implementation files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15622409/15168) and many others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `1_square.c` file to your build command:

```
gcc -o 0_main 0_main.c 1_square.c && ./0_main
```

You need the *definition* of the function as well as its declaration.

From the comments:

> Why then does it need `1_square.c` in the commandline and then also `1_square.h` in the `0_main.c` header?

Like John Bollinger points out in the comments, the only thing `1_square.h` and `1_square.c` have in common is their name, which isn't meaningful to the compiler.  There's no inherent relationship between them as far as gcc is concerned.

Let's start by putting everything in one source file:

```
/** main.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int square( int num );

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  int a = 4;
  int a_squared = square( a );
  printf( "Square of %d is %d\n", a, a_squared );
  return 0;
}

int square( int num )
{
  return num * num;
}
```

In C, a function must be *declared* before it is called in the source code; the declaration introduces the function name, its return type, and the number and types of its arguments.  This will let the compiler verify that the function call is written correctly during translation and issue a diagnostic if it isn't, rather than waiting until runtime to throw an error.  In this particular case, we specify that the `square` function takes a single `int` parameter and returns an `int` value.

This says nothing about the `square` function itself or how it operates - that's provided by the *definition* of the `square` function later on.

A function definition also serves as a declaration; if both the caller and called function are in the same translation unit (source file), then you can put the definition before the call and not have to mess with a separate declaration at all:

```
/** main.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int square( int num )
{
  return num * num;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  int a = 4;
  int a_squared = square( a );
  printf( "Square of %d is %d\n", a, a_squared );
  return 0;
}
```

This is actually preferable as you don't have to update the function signature in two different places.  It means your code reads "backwards", but honestly it's a better way to do it.

However, if you separate your function out into a separate source file, then you need to have a separate declaration:

```
/** main.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int square( int num );

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  int a = 4;
  int a_squared = square( a );
  printf( "Square of %d is %d\n", a, a_squared );
  return 0;
}

/** square.c */
int square( int num )
{
  return num * num;
}
```

When it's processing `main.c`, the compiler doesn't know anything about the *definition* of the `square` function in `square.c` - it doesn't even know the file *exists*.  It doesn't matter if `main.c` is compiled before `square.c` or vice-versa; the compiler operates on one file at a time.  The only thing the compiler knows about the `square` function is that declaration in `main.c`.

Having to manually add a declaration for every function defined in the separate `.c` file is a pain, though - you wouldn't want to write a separate declaration for `printf`, `scanf`, `fopen`, etc.  So ***BY CONVENTION*** we create a separate `.h` file with the same name as the `.c` file to store the declarations:

```
/** main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "square.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  int a = 4;
  int a_squared = square( a );
  printf( "Square of %d is %d\n", a, a_squared );
  return 0;
}

/** square.h */
int square( int num );

/** square.c */
int square( int num )
{
  return num * num;
}
```

By convention, we also add *include guards* to the `.h` file - this keeps the contents of the file from being processed more than once per translation unit, which can happen if you `#include "square.h"` and include another header which *also* includes `square.h`.

```
/** square.h */
#ifndef SQUARE_H       // the contents of this file will only be
#define SQUARE_H       // processed if this symbol hasn't been defined

int square( int num );

#endif
```

Also by convention, we include the `.h` file in the `.c` file to make sure our declarations line up with our definitions - if they don't, the compiler will complain:

```
/** square.c */
#include "square.h"

int square( int num )
{
  return num*num;
}
```

After both `main.c` and `square.c` have been compiled, their object code will be linked into a single executable:

```
main.c ------+-----> compiler ---> main.o ----+--> linker ---> main
             |                                |
square.h ----+                                |
             |                                |
square.c ----+-----> compiler ---> square.o --+
```

We must compile *both* C files and link their object code together to have a working program.  No doubt your IDE makes this easy - you just add source files to the project and it builds them correctly.  `gcc` lets you do it all in one command, but you must list all the `.c` files in the project.

If you're running from the command line, you can use the [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) utility to simplify things.  You'll need to create a Makefile that looks something like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror
main: main.o square.o
all: main
clean:
        rm -rf main *.o
```

All you need to do then is type `make` at the command line and it will build your project, using built-in rules for compiling `main.c` and `square.c`.

Comment: I see, I think when I use the IDE it does a lot of that for me behind the scenes. Why then does it need `1_square.c` in the commandline and then also `1_square.h` in the `0_main.c` header?

Comment: Because, @samuelbrody1249, only convention connects the contents of `1_square.h` with the contents of `1_square.c`.  There is no requirement for any correspondence, so the compiler cannot assume that it should compile the latter just because another source file includes the former.

Comment: @JohnBode wow, what a great answer. Thanks so much for putting in the time.